# Chlorine Cleaner for Car Interior

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I am interested in removing cigarette odor from one car and a vinyl/plasticy smell from another.  I have found a product that is supposed to work for this:  NuVinAir  ([www.nuvinair.com](http://www.nuvinair.com)).  It works by releasing chlorine into the car's interior, which is supposed to permanently neutralize the odors.  A concern I have is any harmful reactions with the chlorine and previous-used vinegar and/or other cleaners on the car's interior.  The SDS of the NuVinAir cleaner is found here:  https://www.nuvinair.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/ReStore-ReFresh_SDS_092920_English-6045980bd30c9f400c01222df27ca08b.pdf

Thanks!

Comment: It certainly does *not* seem a good idea to have chlorine gas released inside a car. Why even consider such a product? If enough gas were released to reach all surfaces and to react with all traces of odor, it likely would be deleterious to both the car *and to you.* See J.D.Power for ideas: https://www.jdpower.com/cars/shopping-guides/how-to-get-smoke-smell-out-of-a-car

Comment: Upon further review it is chlorine dioxide gas, not chlorine.  Does this make it safe to use?

Comment: Chlorine and chlorine dioxide are both toxic gases. If there is a slight excess of any of these gases in the car, it will be deleterious to you.

Answer (score 3):

The cigarette odor and the vinyl odor come into your nose, but their reservoir is not in the atmosphere in the car, but rather on the surfaces where high-boiling compounds have adsorbed and are slowly evaporating.
Fabric especially will hold lots of foul-smelling compounds on the fibers.

I doubt that there is much cigarette odor held *inside* fibers or plastic parts, but the vinyl odor could well be plasticizer slowly coming to the surface.
You might think that leaving the car in the sun with the windows open would slowly evaporate the odorous compounds, but while this might be somewhat true for the cigarette odors, if plasticizer is the source of the vinyl odor, the heat will just bring more up to the surface.

Probably the best way to reduce the odors would be a serious cleaning of the surfaces with a mild soap/detergent, with lots of paper towels - as close as possible to what a professional auto detailer does - followed by placing a car deodorizer somewhere in the car to mask the odors with something more pleasant, like pine.